# How to place search pattern in app.config in C#

Tags: c#, app-config, getfiles

I have the following loop:

```
foreach (var midtier in midtierpath.GetFiles("logfile?.log").Take(1))  //search pattern
```

The search pattern looks for files from `logfile0.log to logfile9.log`
What I would like to do is, instead of having the search pattern hardcoded `("logfile?.log")` in my foreach, to place it in the app.config.
I already tried the following:

```
< appSettings>
    < add key="myFile" value="logfile?.log"/>
< /appSettings>
```

But whenever I'm trying to use the key, it doesn't recognise it as a search pattern but as the actual file name.
Can you please tell me if it's possible to do this or not?

Comment: How are you using the key in the code?

Comment: You don't show the relevant part of your code: how you access and read the key, i.e. its value.

Comment: Please provide us with the code, which *"doesn't recognise it"*. [ask]

Comment: also stick a breakpoint where you call GetFiles and see what the contents of the actual string are, what are they?

Comment: According to some other posts in stackoverflow, it has to be something like that.
    
    
    string myFile = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["myFile"];
    
    foreach (var midtier in midtierpath.GetFiles(myFile).Take(1))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can access Web.Config key name like this:

```
string FilePath = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["myFile"].ToString();
```

Now you can call this in your foreach.

Comment: thanks! This works. I'm new in C# and i totally forgot about .ToString() :/

Comment: You can mark it as answer, if it has helped to solve your problem.